# Owl carousel not working in vite - cannot read property of undefined (reading 'fn')

Tags: jquery, plugins, vite

I updated my dev environment for vite. It's all working fine except an old jQuery plugin, owl.slider. I get that error:

> owl.carousel.js:1718 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
> at owl.carousel.js:1718
> at node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js (owl.carousel.js:1753)
> at __require2 (chunk-IYHMIRNV.js?v=bf03b4af:5)
> at dep:owl_carousel:1

When using webpack I had the same but got it fixed with the ProvidPlugin

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: "jquery",
  jQuery: "jquery",
  "window.jQuery": "jquery",
}),
```

Is there something similar for vite or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have probably figured it out by now, but below is my solution. I hope this will help someone else struggling with the same issue.

vite.config.js file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject';
import htmlPurge from 'vite-plugin-purgecss';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    inject({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
    htmlPurge(),
  ],
  css: {
    devSourcemap: true,
  },
});
```

app.js file:

```
import './app.scss';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'lazysizes';
import 'owl.carousel';

$(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({});
});
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: What do you see in your console? Any error displaying?